# Why does this $.getJSON request error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I have the following script that call a http handler. It calls the http handler, and in fiddler, I can see the JSON returned correctly, however this script always ends up in the error block. How can I determine what is wrong?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function GetConfig() {
            $.getJSON("http://localhost:27249/Handlers/GetServiceMenuConfiguration.ashx", function(d) {
                alert("success");
            }).success(function(d) {
                alert("success");
            }).error(function(d) {
                alert("error");
            }).complete(function(d) {
                alert("complete");
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Could you provide us with the post back? and is the post back valid JSON? Headers from the post back ect, would be nice.

Comment: use JSONLint and check if returned JSON is well formed

Comment: Your error handler gets three arguments, two of which are useful for figuring out what the error is. What do they show?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I couldn't see useful information, what arg should I be looking at?

Comment: @MrShoubs: The error function gets three args described in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/): `jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown`. The first is just the jQuery XHR object. The second and third are usually more informative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see that you're including the server name (`localhost`) and port (`27249`). Ajax requests are controlled by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which forbids cross-origin requests in the normal case. (If you're not doing a cross-origin call, you don't need to include the `http://localhost:27249` portion of your URL, which is what makes me think you might be doing one.)

You can do cross-origin calls if the browser supports them and if your server code handles the [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) requests properly. Alternately, you might look at using [JSON-P](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP).

Comment: I assumed both handler and site running on local host would be treated as same domain - you mention origin. I'll put the web page in the same project as the handler. This is the first web dev I've done. Ever. (usually a .net dev)

Comment: @MrShoubs: Besides the same domain, AJAX calls need to be on the same port too.

Comment: Thanks @Rocket I'm finding there are lot of things catching me out.

Comment: @MrShoubs: *Origin* is different from *domain*. Different ports are different origins (as are different protocols -- `http` vs. `https` -- and even different subdomains, although that's easier to relax). See the link for details.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's built-in JSON parser is rather picky, even well formatted JSON can sometimes fail if the headers are not set perfectly. First try to do a $.ajax request with type:text property and log the response. This will differentiate between a connection problem and parse problem.

```
$.ajax({
  dataType:'text',
  url: '/Handlers/GetServiceMenuConfiguration.ashx',
  success: function(data) {
      console.log(data.responseText);
  }
});
```

If the problem is the connection, and you do need to request JSON across domains, then you could also use a library loader like LAB, yep/nope or [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js).

Comment: *"JQuery's built-in JSON parser is rather picky, even well formatted JSON can sometimes fail if the headers are not set perfectly"* No. Well-formed JSON will parse if you tell jQuery it's JSON. You do that in one of two ways: 1. Return the correct `Content-Type` header. 2. Just tell jQuery you're expecting JSON back (via the `dataType` option), in which case it will ignore the `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Thanks for your comments TJ and I respect your opinion a lot, but mileage may vary. There are a host of things that can be incorrectly configured on the server to cause $.getJSON to not parse even well-formatted JSON. That is one reason why this same question shows up again and again.

Comment: @ Bishop: Can you point me at even one of them? Because frankly, I've never heard anything like that at all. I see **lots** of people asking about JSON errors, and they almost always come down to badly-formed JSON, the SOP, or making the call incorrectly.

Comment: You mentioned one: the Content-Type header. I am guessing that other headers could throw off the connection as well. Improper character encoding/escaping could make the JSON appear well formatted on the server, but would cause the JSON interpreter to fail. Depending on the server product you are using (such as cold fusion), the response may be prepended with a security string to prevent phishing. This won't appear server side, but will cause the JSON to fail. Some servers don't handle HTML content inside JSON correctly, and so errors might be intermittent depending on the content of the JSON.

Comment: @ Bishop: Okay, encoding could be an issue, though you'd have to be very unlucky for it to actually cause the parsing to fail. Pre-pending things or server-side failure handling HTML both qualify as incorrectly-formed JSON from the client perspective. :-)